# Impact on having large number of consumers on producers / brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I wanted to understand, having large numbers of consumers on producer latency and brokers. I have around 7K independent consumers. Each consumer is consuming all partitions of a topic. I have manually assigned partitions of a topic to a consumer, not using consumer groups. Each consumer is consuming msg only one topic. Message size is small less than a KB. Produce throughput is also low. But when produce spike come then produce latency (here ack=1). Brokers resource is also very low. I want to understand the impact on having large number of consumers on Kafka.

*Cluster Details:*

```
Broker#: 13 (1 Broker : 14 cores & 36GB memory  )
Kafka cluster version: 2.0.0
Kafka Java client version: 2.0.0
Number topics: ~15. 
Number of consumers: 7K (all independent and manually assigned all partitions of a topic to a consumers. One consumer is consuming all partitions from a topic only)
```

Comment: Are you measuring network saturation?

Comment: @cricket_007, network is not getting chocked because message size is very small and produce rate is very low.

Comment: But when all the consumers are started, are they reading all messages in the topics, or just the latest?

Comment: No just latest, even after restart of consumers, i set the latest offset  to consumers and then they start consuming.